# Is the @joinColumn name attribute necessary for ManyToOne relationships?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Going through [this tutorial on how to implement equals and hashcode](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) for JPA entities and it annotates the `Company` reference in `Product` like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", 
            nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Company company;
```

Is the `name = "company_id"` part necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column `name` is only required to DEFINE the SCHEMA. It is not essential since there is a default name assigned with the JPA API

> (Default only applies if a single join column is used.) The
>   concatenation of the following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referencing entity or embeddable
>   class; "*"; the name of the referenced primary key column. If there is
>   no such referencing relationship property or field in the entity, or
>   if the join is for an element collection, the join column name is
>   formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the entity;
>   "*"; the name of the referenced primary key column.

In addition, arguably, it is not great practice to hard code schema info in annotations anyway, in case they need changing at deployment time.